# jQuery Hover Toggle Fix

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of products that on each individual hover, will toggle-in a `div` with the image/add to cart button. However, every time I hover over the items quickly, they all somewhat flash.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vJX5g/3/)

Is there a better jQuery way to toggle the individual grid item's respective hover `div` without the flash?

Comment: Do you want it like this >> http://jsfiddle.net/vJX5g/29/ <<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add in `$.stop()` to prevent it from queueing up more animations:

```
$(".grid li").hoverIntent(
    function(){
        $(".grid-hover", this).stop().delay(500).fadeIn();
    },
    function(){
        $(".grid-hover", this).stop().fadeOut();
    }            
);
```

It's a bit difficult to get this perfect, however I believe in this instance [`$.hoverIntent()`](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent) may be a better tool to use than the native `$.hover()`.

Comment: I have never used `hoverIntent`. +1 for something new for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit closer to a more comfortable feeling UI experience:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.grid li').hover(function(){

        $('.grid-hover').stop();
        $('.grid-hover').fadeOut(500);
        $('.grid-hover', this).fadeIn(500);

    }, function(){

        $('.grid-hover', this).fadeOut(500);

    });

});
```

Not perfect.. to be sure. The on hover jquery event is tricky to get right; especially with animations. Have to carefully follow the logic and timings of things. I'd play around with the `.stop()` jQuery function, which stops animations on elements; as well as the `setTimeout()` JavaScript function.